# samba = nouser, make dropbox use same usr

Tags: 16.04, server, samba, lts, dropbox

SO here is my issue. I have a `Ubuntu 16.04.3 server` setup.
I set raid on the server for protection. 
mounted raid to `/mnt/Dropbox`

There are multiples computer that connect to the files on the server. The people using these computers are not savvy enough to know how to log into the server therefore my `smb.conf` is set to `guest= ok` and I have `chmod 777` and chown nobody.nogroup

Then `mkdir ~/Dropbox` and `ln` to `/mnt/Dropbox`

installed `dropbox`

Now the issue... while my file will sync to the folder... they are protected via root. Now I tried to fallow the directions at:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-dropbox-client-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-14-04

I set `DROPBOX_USERS="nobody"`

but thus the dropbox doesn't want to start.

The issue is... when it's synced via dropbox the windows users cannot access/edit/delete the files because of the permissions.

What am I missing?! got an easier idea?

Comment: How do you start dropbox?